# How to correct the mesh deformation from the weight painting?

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

I am working on my first simulation, which is a bike with a cyclist, and after doing some weight-painting I noticed that the pedalboard was severely deformed. I made some adjustments on it with the painting but there are still parts that I don't successfully correct, plus the angle of the mechanism has changed for no reason.
If someone has any idea on how I can fix that, it would be helpful. Thank you

PS : I join screenshots of how it was before and what i got now. My problem is not on the crank, it was good before my last change but really on the pedalboard.

[image: Here is what I obtained after the weight painting]

[image: Here is what it looked like before]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a bicycle, which is made of rigid, articulated pieces, there shouldn't be any need for weight painting.  Each rigid piece should have its own bone, and should either be bone parented to that bone rather than armature deformed (which is better performance) or should be solidly weighted at 1.0 to that bone and to no other bones (which is worse performance, but there may be some reasons to prefer being able to keep the entire bicycle as a single object, even if that means paying the price of armature "deformation".)

If going the armature route, the proper way to weight a bicycle does not involve weight paint at all:

1. In object mode, parent the bicycle to the armature with empty groups to create vertex groups with the same names as your bone.
2. In edit mode, select linked to select entire chunks of your bicycle, then select the vertex group with the appropriate bone name in properties/object data/vertex groups, make sure "Weight:" in that panel is set to 1.0, and click the "Assign" button in that panel.

As more general advice, bits of meshes won't deform when they have uniform weights.  If all vertices of the pedalboard have the exact same weights, the pedalboard won't change shape.  For situations like character armor, where you want similar rigidity, but you may actually want the piece weighted to multiple bones, this can be achieved most easily by selecting all vertices of the rigid bit in edit or weight paint, actively selecting a central vertex, and then clicking the "copy" button on sidebar/item/vertex weights.  This will set the vertex group values of all selected vertices to that of the actively selected vertex so that the selection has uniform weights.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have an armature which is taking both the body of the cyclist and also the mechanism of the bicycle (pedals and cranks), because it was made in one part and I wanted to make the cranks move along with feet passing by the pedals.
Would dividing this armature in two armatures, one for the body and the other for the mechanism be more efficient ? 
Or perhaps, following your first piece of advice, should I have a specific piece for each part of the mechanism linked to the pedalboard (cranks, pedals) as for now, it is just a unique piece ?

Comment: You could have two armatures, or you could have one, there are small reasons for either and it doesn't matter too much in this case.

Comment: Alright thank you